# Though the query run correctly, when creating and selecting a view i get an error

Tags: view, sql-server-2016

I create a big query with a lot of  joins (self and inner). When i run it i get the result properly. I create a view using that query and when i am selecting the view i get the following error:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 221
>
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 221
>
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post view create script.

Comment: Are you using `=*` old style joins?

Comment: The script is very large. I cannot post it. No i am not using =* joins. All the joins are either left join, inner join or self join.